# HTML5 Elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

I would use HTML5 for my new Blog Design. I have used HTML5 Tags like `<header>` `<article>` and `<footer>`.

The problem is, that these elements don't work on IE 6, 7 and 8. I know that HTML5 is not supported on these IE versions. I have it tried with the modernizr script and `document.createElement("header" );` JS-function.

But none of this works for me! I can't make the Tags, What can I do?

EDIT:

Thank you @all for you answers! :)

I have tried it with "html5shiv" and with the code from armonge. But these elements are furthermore unstyled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the HTML5 shiv script..

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

<strike>I think all you need so is link it in the head of your document</strike>

Quote from the source ;)

> To use this script, it must be
>   included before the `<body>` element
>   (i.e. in the `<head>`) but doesn't
>   matter if it appears before or after
>   the CSS - but for the sake of
>   performance, it would make better
>   sense to include the CSS first then
>   this script.

Comment: Check out Dive into HTML5 http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html This chapter talks about what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<!--[if  lte IE 8]>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
        var html5elmeents = "address|article|aside|audio|canvas|command|datalist|details|dialog|figure|figcaption|footer|header|hgroup|keygen|mark|meter|menu|nav|progress|ruby|section|time|video".split('|');
          for(var i = 0; i < html5elmeents.length; i++){
            document.createElement(html5elmeents[i]);
          }
        }
      )();
    </script> 
<![endif]-->
```